# Why my c++ algorithm is always returning the same value for Min and Max figure of a number?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have been writing some simple algorihtms and I am facing with a problem. I am writing an algorithm for showing the minimum and the maximum figure of a number. It works, but it only returns the maximum for both cases and I can't figure why. Thanks a lot !!!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Citire(int& n)
{ cout  <<"\nDa numarul:";
  cin   >>n;
  while (n<=0)
    {cout<<"ai gresit, da natural:";
     cin >>n;
    }
}

int CifMinMax(int n)
{
    int Max = 9;
    int Min = 0;
    int UltCif;

    while (n>0)
    {
        UltCif = n % 10;

        if (UltCif < Min)
          Min = UltCif;

        if (UltCif > Max)
            Max = UltCif;

    n = n/10;
    }

    return Max, Min;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int Min;
    int Max;

    Citire(n);
    Min = CifMinMax(n);
    Max = CifMinMax(n);

    cout <<endl<<Min<<" este cifra minima a numarului, iar "<<Max<<" este cifra maxima a numarului." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `CifMinMax` function returns an `int`. What do you think `return Max, Min;` results in?

Comment: Why would you expect something different to happen when you call the same function twice?

Comment: Change function prototype to `void CifMinMax(int n, int& Min, int& Max)`

Comment: Not working. It says: too few arguments to function (int n, int& Min, int& Max) ...

Comment: @Ezekiel ... read the error message, understand it and adjust the function call.

Comment: @Ezekiel, Alex' suggestion should be interpreted as containing an implicit "and modify the call accordingly".

Comment: You can't return two values from a function like that. There are alternatives available. Returning a struct (like std::pair) or using reference parameters.

Comment: Why do you int the maximum with `9` and the minimum with `0`? That sounds totally wrong!

Answer (score 8):

```
return Max, Min;
```

This line actually returns `Min` discarding `Max`. Read about `operator ,` it evaluates its operands from left to right and returns the last one, that's why you are getting the same values.

You need something like this:

```
std::pair<int, int> CifMinMax(int n)
{
    // ...
    return std::make_pair(Min, Max);
}

std::pair<int, int> MinMax = CifMinMax(n);
Min = MinMax.first;
Max = MinMax.second;
```

Comment: Now it returns always 0 for the Min and for the Max it returns correct.

Comment: What do you expect it to return for the `Min`? You initialize `Min` with 0 and update it when `UltCif < Min`, but `UltCif = n % 10`, which is always >0 IIRC. I wonder why it returns correct `Max` for the same reason.

Comment: Sorry. My mind was to something else. Min and Max should be equal to n % 10 and now it works properly. I forgot to change their initialization. Sorry for that. Thanks a lot !!!